# Has anybody out there used Delphi for programming VST's?

Tags: delphi, vst

Has anybody out there used Delphi for programming a Virtual Studio Technology plugin?

Answer (score 9):

Yep, using Christian Budde's ASIO and VST Framework, which is probably the easiest way to get going in Delphi, available here http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/.

He's got a lot of real examples (ie. not just simple, minimal delays) and at the Developer forum at KVR (http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33) you'll find a number of people using it and discussing it.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I haven't, but there is the [Delphi VST SDK](http://www.axiworld.be/vst.html), so I assume at least Frederic Vanmol has.  There are samples too, so it should be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Several people have used Delphi to release both commercial and free VST plugins. Some examples of Delphi made plugins are [Glitch](http://illformed.org/plugins/glitch/), [Poise](http://www.onesmallclue.com/poise.php) and [Jamstix](http://www.rayzoon.com/)

These links might be useful when starting to project VST plugins in Delphi

- [Tobybear's Delphi VST Template](http://www.tobybear.de/d_template.html)
- [Delphi ASIO & VST Packages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/)
- [Delphi translation of the VST SDK](http://www.axiworld.be/vst.html) by Frederic Vanmol